# Multiple Local Network Gateway objects with same address space

Tags: vpn, azure, site-to-site-vpn

I have multiple internet providers. For my Azure instances I'd like to be able to define a local network gateway for each with the same address space so that I can easily switch between them in the event of a failure.

Is it safe / possible to do so? I'd be concerned that these objects could be used for routing on Azure's side and could end up resulting in a split route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it safe / possible to do so?

Of course.

> I'd be concerned that these objects could be used for routing on Azure's side and could end up resulting in a split route.

Your concern is reasonable and Azure has a solution for this.

When there are two redundant VPN devices on the local network, the site-to-site VPN must be connected with BGP enabled.

In this case, the prefix you need to declare for the local network gateway is the host address of your BGP Peer IP address on your VPN device. (e.g.10.10.10.254/32) So that the prefix won't be overlap on multiple local gateways and the routing will be handled by BGP.

Here is a good [guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-activeactive-rm-powershell) about how to configure that with Powershell commands.